# Install Chrome extension from Chrome packaged app

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I have chrome packaged app in Chrome Web Store and extension which
should communicate with app and extend its functionality.
Is there any way to automatically install extension when user 
installing app from chrome store?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Not even the strongest API for managing extensions, `chrome.management`, can install something not already installed.

I don't need to say why this would be an obviously bad idea from security perspective.

What you should do is explain why you need it, and provide a link to Web Store install page.